# PHP : load another php file source and replace all instances of string "<?php ... ?>"

Tags: php, regex

I have a .php file which is actually an SVG file with some inline PHP code. Lets call it `inner.php` :

```
<?php 
    $uuid = uniqid();
?>
<svg class="__combo" id=<?php echo $uuid ?>
...
</svg>
```

I am writing another php file which should emit the content of inner.php but with all instances of `<?php ... ?>` replaced by some string ( for example "AA").The file (lets call it outer.php) looks like this now :

```
    <?php 
        $svg_body = file_get_contents("inner.php"));
        $replaced = preg_replace("??","AA" , $svg_body);

        echo "$replaced"
    ?>
```

I marked with "??" the part where I would like to put a regular expression to contain any string starting with `"<?php"` and ending with first occurrence of `"?>"`.  And the output I expect to see is

```
    "AA"
    <svg class="__combo" id="AA"
    ...
    </svg>
```

Basically, I dont find a way to escape string containing the `<?php` and `?>` in PHP

Comment: As a note, `str_replace` replaces raw strings, but for regular expressions, you'll want to use [`preg_replace`](https://php.net/preg-replace) instead.

Comment: @ChrisForrence - thanks for the info and the link. I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression seems to work fine...

```
preg_replace('/<\?(php\s|=).*\?>/siU', '"AA"', $svg_body);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/0Ci9d

To break it down...

- `<\?(php\s|=)` - a literal match for `"<?php"` (question-mark escaped) followed by a whitespace character (could be newline) or the short-echo `<?=`
- `.*` - zero or more characters
- `\?>` - a literal match for `"?>"`
- `s` - sets `*` to match over newlines, required for your first `<?php ... ?>` block
- `i` - case-insensitive because why not
- `U` - ungreedy. Means `*` matches stops at the first following pattern, not the last. This is to prevent `*` from matching everything between the first `"<?php"` and the last `"?>"`

See here for more information on the modifiers ~ http://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is using PHP's parser via the tokenizer Extension:

```
<?php

$tokens = token_get_all("<svg>\n<?php echo; ?></svg>");

$result='';
$in_php = false;
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
   if ($token[0]==T_INLINE_HTML) {
     $result .= $token[1];
     $in_php = false;
   } else if (!$in_php) {
     $result .= "AAA";
     $in_php=true;
    }
}

echo $result;
```

https://3v4l.org/jEpYi

This has the benefit, that it also handles other open tags, like `<?=` and files without closing tag. And handles cases where the closing tag also appears in PHP code (I.e. in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this without RegEx first. You may try with `substr_replace`.

```
$replaced = substr_replace($svg_body, 'AA', strpos($svg_body, '<?php'), strpos($svg_body, '?>'));
```

if you really need RegEx then try something like this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace(/(<\?php[\s\S]+?\?>)/, "AA", $svg_body);
```

Comment: Won't this only replace the first occurrence?

Comment: Then loop it! OP didn't specify how many times the needle would appear in the haystack.

Comment: Well, it's at least twice in their example

Comment: @Dharman - thanks, but I did say "all instances". Anyway, your answer is still educational